# Socket.IO 1.2.1 and Flash ping time out

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a multi player game using NodeJS and Socket.IO (v 1.2.1) for the server backend and Flash for the client. With Flash I'm using this for connecting to Socket.IO (https://github.com/redannick/FlashSocket.IO/tree/1.0.x).

The main problem I've is that during the gameplay after around 10 minutes some clients disconnect due to ping time out. I made NodeJS print logs and what I get is:

```
engine:ws writing "3" +0ms
socket.io:client client close with reason ping timeout +40.2m
socket.io:socket closing socket - reason ping timeout +40.2m
socket.io:client ignoring remove for l7G1SDolb60nG3XRAAAA +1ms
User disconnected. Reason: ping timeout
```

Something similar in the Flash console:

```
pong - 20:23:41 - stop
pong - 22:12:8 - start
webSocketFatal: Server Timed Out!!
```

Normally I've 5 players per room and only 2 - 3 get that and almost all at the same time.
My connection code is:

```
        _socket = new FlashSocket("http://"+Constants.IP+":"+Constants.PORT);

        // Set up internal events
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT, onConnect);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.MESSAGE, onMessage);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.IO_ERROR, onConnectError);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onConnectError);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        _socket.addEventListener(FlashSocketEvent.CLOSE, onDisconnect);

        // Set up external events
        _socket.addEventListener(SetUserNameResponse, onSetUserNameResponse);
        _socket.addEventListener(SetLobbyResponse, onSetLobbyResponse);
        _socket.addEventListener(PlayerConnectionEvent, onPlayerConnectionEvent);
        _socket.addEventListener(PlayerDisconnectionEvent, onPlayerDisconnectionEvent);
        _socket.addEventListener(ChatMessageReceived, onChatMessageReceived);
        _socket.addEventListener(IsReady, onIsReady);
        _socket.addEventListener(GoToPhase, onGoToPhase);
        _socket.addEventListener(SendOpinionToVote, onSendOpinionToVote);
        _socket.addEventListener(PlayerVotedOpinion, onPlayerVotedOpinion);
        _socket.addEventListener(AnnouncePhaseResult, onAnnouncePhaseResult);
        _socket.addEventListener(GoToReadyPhase, onGoToReadyPhase);
        _socket.addEventListener(IsCorrupt, onIsCorrupt);
        _socket.addEventListener(AnnouncePhaseResultFinalGame, onAnnouncePhaseResultFinalGame);
```

And the server code:

```
/**
 * The port we will listen to.
 */
ServerManager.prototype.start = function(server)
{
    this.io = require('socket.io')(
    {
        transports : [ 'flashsocket', 'websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'polling'],
    });

    // Set up connection event
    var _this = this;
    this.io.on('connection', function(socket) { _this.onConnection(socket); });

    // Start the server
    this.io.listen(server);
    console.log("Server listening on port " + this.port);
};


/**
 * Callback for new connections.
 */
ServerManager.prototype.onConnection = function(socket)
{
    console.log("New connection");

    // Set up connection event
    var _this = this;

    socket.on('SUN', function(data) { _this.onSetUserName(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('SL', function(data) { _this.onSetLobby(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('CM_S', function(data) { _this.onSendChatMessage(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('IMR', function(data) { _this.onImReady(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('SOV', function(data) { _this.onSendOpinionVote(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('SCV', function(data) { _this.onSendCaseVote(socket, data); } );
    socket.on('EL', function(data) { _this.onExitLobby(socket, data); } );

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) { _this.onDisconnect(socket, data); } );
};
```

I'm not sure if the problem is due to flash, due to Socket.IO or why does it happen. I tried changing the WebSocket library in Flash, and it still happened, I tried updating Socket.IO (I used to use 1.0.6) and it still happened. I'm also not sure if it happens due to having the game on another tab and flash freezing or something.

Thank you very much for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

You simple need a "keep-alive" message - a simple message that's sent from the client to the server every X seconds to keep the connection alive (i.e. let the server know that the client is still connected).

Just set up a `Timer` to run every 30 seconds, and send a message (e.g. the string "ping", but it doesn't matter what) to the server.

This is pretty common; there's nothing in particular wrong with your code or setup.

Comment: btw: "I'm also not sure if it happens due to having the game on another tab" - if flash detects that it loses focus (i.e. you go to another tab), then it'll automatically throttle the frame rate to something like 5fps - the very lowest to keep network connections and streaming media working. This will affect the fidelity of your `Timer`, so keep this in mind